# Firebase: Firestorage storage provider.ts:239 Uncaught Error: Component analytics has not been registered yet

Tags: javascript, forms, web, web-applications, firebase-storage

I am unable to connect the data storage with my firebase,
below is the cdn script code.  * contains the number generated from **firebase,** have just hide for the security reasons.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getDatabase, ref, set, get, child } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-database.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"; 

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "*",
        authDomain: "majorproj-auth.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "majorproj-auth",
        storageBucket: "majorproj-auth.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "*",
        appId: "*",
        measurementId: "*"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getDatabase(app);
    
    // Initialize Firebase Analytics after initializing Firebase App
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        set(ref(db, 'complaints/' + document.getElementById("fname").value),
 {
            fname: document.getElementById("fname").value,
            lname: document.getElementById("lname").value,
            email: document.getElementById("email").value,
            phone: document.getElementById("phone").value,
            complaint: document.getElementById("complaint").value,
            platform: document.getElementById("platform").value,
            country: document.getElementById("country").value,
            datecomplaint: document.getElementById("datecomplaint").value,
        });

        // Assuming 'fname' is a unique identifier for your data
        
        alert("Details Submitted !");
    });
```

error I am facing:

`provider.ts:239  Uncaught Error: Component analytics has not been registered yet`
`at Provider.initialize (provider.ts:239:13)`
`at initializeAnalytics (api.ts:127:23)`
`at getAnalytics (api.ts:95:17)`
`at complaint.html?`

how do I register...its capturing the data but unable to recognize it